# call local variable from another function with the argument, shows error

Tags: python, python-3.x

when i run this program i got this error, and what if i put board in `display_board` as argument and then call it with an empty list like that `display_board([])`

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\withrajat\eclipse-workspace\LCO\tictactoe.py", line 31, in <module>
    player_input()
  File "C:\Users\withrajat\eclipse-workspace\LCO\tictactoe.py", line 29, in player_input
    board.replace("O", marker)
NameError: name 'board' is not defined
```

The code:

```
from random import randint
#Step 1: Write a function that can print out a board. Set up your board as a list,
#where each index 1-9 corresponds with a number on a number pad, so you get a 3 by 3 board representation.
def display_board():
    board = []
    for play in range(0,3):
        board.append(["O"]*3)
    for joinBoard in board:
        print(" ".join(joinBoard))



#Step 2: Write a function that can take in a player input and assign their marker as 'X' or 'O'.
#Think about using while loops to continually ask until you get a correct answer.

def player_input():
    print("Type the board in which you want play? 'X' or 'O'")
    marker = str(input(" 'X' or 'O' ")).upper()
    print("You chose {} as a board, now we'll assign it.".format(marker))
    col_random = randint(0,3)
    print(col_random)
    row_random = randint(0,3)
    print(row_random)
    print("\n Now we'll ask you to guess the position of hidden ")
    col_guess= int(input('Guess the colum: >> '))
    row_guess = int(input('Guess the row: >> '))
    while col_guess == col_random and row_guess == row_random:
        display_board().board.replace("O", marker)


player_input()
```

my question is how can i call that variable in another function and please tell me how can i do that if i pass that empty list as an argument and remove the board variable inside the display_board function. please help me i am new to programming.

Comment: what do you think `display_board().board.replace("O", marker)` does?

Comment: replace the O item with the X or O i guess!

Comment: Does the function `display_board` return anything?

Comment: no it doesn't return anything...

Comment: if `display_board` doesn't return anything. Then `display_board().board` is going to be an issue. Do you see why?

Comment: It seems you already know the answer. If you want to use a variable used in another function, you have to declare it as a global variable. See these: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: @PedroMaimere, no need for a global here.

Comment: that's problem i don't want to use the global @PedroMaimere

Comment: so why not return the board and then call `.replace` on the returned board?

Comment: @Skam i am not getting this, why this is issue if that func doesn't return anything because there is no requirement of returning anything. please explain this, please

Comment: @Skam it's not working after returning the board, it gave me another error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'board'

Comment: thanks @Skam  and  it worked, thanks a lot, i used indexing instead of .replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your suspect line of code.

`display_board().board.replace("O", marker)`

Now, what exactly does this do? We can expand this line to some equivalent code because you're skipping a few major steps.

```
printed_board = display_board()
printed_board.replace('O', marker)
```

Based on the code you have above, `display_board` doesn't return anything so if you were to `print(printed_board)` you would see `printed_board == None` and `None.board.replace('O', marker)` is going to throw an error because `None` doesn't have any properties or functions.

There are a few ways to fix this as described in the comments that I don't explicitly write out for you here because this is a good exercise in debugging but I would definitely **NOT** use a global variable.

Comment: Okay! I got this, 1. is is necessary  to put this line printed_board = display_board() or we can do it direct?

Comment: While it's not necessary, I encourage new coders to do it so you can see/understand exactly what each line is doing. Complex lines like that are harder to debug.

Comment: i have replaced "display_board().board.replace("O", marker)" with "display_board()[col_guess-1][row_guess-1] == marker
        print(display_board())" but it's not changing the item, why?